# Testing `(?=\d)\w(?=\d)` on `123abc456`

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I was testing the regex `(?=\d)\w(?=\d)` on the string `123abc456`. My expectation was that the positive lookahead `(?=\d)` should match `1` and discard it ( since lookaheads are zero length assertions) and then `\w` should match`2` and the second positive look ahead should just match`3` and discard it. Thus, we have an overall match of just `2`.

However, pythex yields the match as `12` and `45` . Where could I be going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Precisely *because* the lookahead is zero-length, the `1` is not consumed by `(?=\d)`, but only matched.

Comment: @chepner so `1` shouldn't be included in the overall match?

Comment: Why do you think first `1` should not be matched when it satisfies all the assertions?

Comment: `(?=\d)\w(?=\d)` = `\d(?=\d)` [matches](https://regex101.com/r/Uv49cN/1) a digit followed with any other digit.

Comment: What are you testing with? `re.findall("(?=\d)\w(?=\d)", "123abc456")` find 4 matches, `1`, `2`, `4`, and `5`, being the 4 characters that both are and are followed by digits.

Comment: `(?=\d)` matches but does not consume 1, then `\w` both matches *and* consumes 1, and `(?=\d)` matches but does not consume `2`. That leaves `2` as the first character in the string to which `re.findall` applies the regular expression again.

Comment: *"`(?=\d)` should match `1` and discard it ( since lookaheads are zero length assertions) and then `\w` should match `2`"* - No, exactly because it's non-consuming, the `\w` will match `1`...

Comment: The match result at pythex.org is ambiguous, as the results for your regex and `(?=\d)\w\w(?=\d)` look identical.

Comment: The linked duplicate doesn't explain how a zero-length lookahead works, which is the crux of the OP's question.